# Run event on workflow hydration/dehydration?

Tags: workflow, site, persistence

Is it possible to add hydration/dehydration events to a workflow? (this is a Site state machine workflow if it matters, SP 2010).

Comment: I guess hydrated/dehydrated are run by system automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though SharePoint workflows are in fact WF (Windows Workflow Foundation) workflows and the WF WorkflowRuntime has the WorkflowPersisted, WorkflowUnloaded and WorkflowLoaded events, SharePoint doesn't provide you access to any of these.

Comment: I pretty much figured as much but hoped I was wrong :(